# Get value of span tag in jasmine angular2 testing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here is my html code

```
<span class="boxText">
            {{model.number}}
    <i *ngIf="model.canText" class="fa fa-comment" placement="right"></i>
</span>
```

There is only one span tag in my code. I want to test if span tag contains the specific value, i.e model.number.

Here I am able to get the span element.

```
let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.boxText'));
let spanEl = el.nativeElement;
```

But not able check if the value exist. How do i do this using jasmine?

Comment: Have you tried -> fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.boxText'))[0]   and then -> el.value ?

Comment: I tried now, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: can you upload a pic of this console.log(spanEl) ?
Have you tried this spanEl.innerHTML ? it has to be like that, it's just accessing the element value, shouldn't be complex but without seeing what you're getting it's impossible

Comment: @Alejandro Lora You are right here, spanEl.innerHTML will give the text within it. And then I could do `expect(spanEl.innerHTML).toContain(component.model.number);` Thanks much!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I leave here the answer for someone else, but it was just accessing the element as on plain js.

```
let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.boxText'));
let spanEl = el.nativeElement;
// spanEl.innerHTML => give you the value
```

and test like normally

```
expect(spanEl.innerHTML).toContain(component.model.number);
```